# grid layout support for ModPE GUI library

Tags: javascript, java, android, rhino

I am making a library for ModPE scripters to help them put GUI in their mods. This update will add support for gridlayout instead of just linearlayout. Now I know I cant do this if their is to be flexibility with what content they put in. So what I am thinking is.. can I arrange a list and then use a for loop in the class to put it all one by one? I understand this post does not follow the proper question policies here so I will put it in the best words I can put it into. Take the linear layout class for example on the basic set up

```
var ctx = com.mojang.minecraftpe.MainActivity.currentMainActivity.get();
var linear = {
    Button: function(location1, location2, num1, num2, size1, size2, buttonString, yourFunction)
    {
        ctx.runOnUiThread(new java.lang.Runnable() {
            run: function()
            {
                try
                {
                    var defaultLayout = new android.widget.LinearLayout(ctx);
                    var defaultButton = new android.widget.Button(ctx);
                    defaultButton.setText(buttonString);
                    defaultLayout.addView(defaultButton);
                    var defaultPopup = new android.widget.PopupWindow(defaultLayout, size1, size2);
                    defaultPopup.showAtLocation(ctx.getWindow().getDecorView(), location1 | location2, num1, num2);
                    defaultButton.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
                        onClick: function()
                        {
                            try{yourFunction()}catch(error){print(error)}
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch(defaultError){print(defaultError);}
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Well I need to do something like that but with grid layout is there a way I can make two parameters as lists then have a for loop go through each one and place them in the gridlayout? I know this question doesnt fit here very well but if you need more info just ask

Comment: Answered in another question